# RE: Updating Choice Parameter in Deploy Job from the post actions of Build Job without building it

Tags: jenkins

I have two pipeline jobs (one for Build and another for Deployment) in jenkins and deployment job builds on one choice parameter which needs values(tags) from docker hub.

What we want to do is, To just update the choice field of deploy job from the build job post actions with out building it. Is that possible anyway?

Comment: There's also a question about this on devops.stackexchange: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/get-changes-of-the-parameterized-pipeline-on-the-fly-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible at the moment. You need to run a build to update the parameters.

There are some tickets for this on the Jenkins Jira: [JENKINS-52939](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52939) [JENKINS-50365](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50365). The latter is marked as "Fixed but unreleased", but it doesn't appear to be actually fixed yet.

One comment mentions a workaround. You can put this in your pipeline to update the parameters and then abort the build:

```
stages {
    stage("parameterizing") {
        steps {
            script {
                if ("${params.Invoke_Parameters}" == "Yes") {
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    error('DRY RUN COMPLETED. JOB PARAMETERIZED.')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```